# First Derivative Test - Given turning points, find co-efficients

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am struggling with this question:

> The graph of the function $y = x^3+ax^2+bx+c$ passes through (1,1) and has turning points at $x=-1$ and $x=3$. Find $a$, $b$ and $c$.

---

**My approach**:

I equated $x=1$ and $y=1$ and found that $a+b+c = 0$  (EQUATION 1)

Later, i equated $x=-1$ and $x=3$ in the $y'(x)$ equation $3x^2+2ax+b$ and found 2 simultaneous equations

> $2a-b = 3$  (EQUATION 2)

> $6a+b = -27$ (EQUATION 3)

that gave me $a = -3$

Next, I used $a = -3$ in one of the simultaneous equations i found above to get $b = -9$ and since $a+b+c = 0$, $c = 12$.

I know I am going wrong somewhere because answers on the back of my book are:

> $a = (-30/7)$, $b = (-81/7)$ and $c = (120/7)$

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: If that's the case, we can differentiate the expression and equate it to zero, and find relations that can be used to solve the problem, I guess....

Comment: Is is so, @J.W.Tanner ?

Comment: That's what he did.

Comment: @Koro Aren't those points of inflection?

Comment: $\frac{-30}{7}+\frac{120}{7}+\frac{-81}{7} \neq 0$. Then the graph would never passes through (1,1). So the answers must be wrong i think...

Comment: Of course! I wonder how i missed that. Thank you, @PAM1499

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are absolutely correct. Here's your answer's graph

[image: Graph]

It also passes through $(1,1)$

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! @datboi

Comment: You are welcome!